# Use WMI to create DNS entries

Tags: dns, wmi

Is it possible to create DNS entries using WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help: **[Add DNS Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682130(VS.85).aspx#_dns_add_a_resource_record)**

**EDIT:** Here's a VBScript [snippet](http://www.winscripter.com/WSH/ADSI/272.aspx) that might be useful

```
 var sHostName = "SomeMachine"
 var strRRsufix    = ". IN A 192.168.51.200";  //some ip address
 var strRR= sHostName + strRRsufix;
 var objDNS       = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\MicrosoftDNS");
 var objRR        = objDNS.Get("MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord");
 var objDNSServer = objDNS.Get("MicrosoftDNS_Server.Name=\".\"");
 objRR.CreateInstanceFromTextRepresentation(objDNSServer.Name, strDomain, strRR);
```

Comment: hmmm I'll try that. Seems like it's not exactly straightforward, especially with impersonation ?!. But thanks alot for digging this up, its a good starting point :)